# creating an expression that acts like a .contains

Tags: javascript, extjs

I have a list/store with values. Right now I have autocompletion that will suggest values that start with the letter that is given on they keyboard. But what I (think) need instead of: `this.getRawValue()` is an expression that will show all the values that contain that letter, and not only the values that start with the given letter.
So if I type 'D', it should also show the name 'Sander', which doesn't start with D, but contains D.

This is the specific code:

```
this.getStore().filter('NAME', this.getRawValue());
```

I know that javascript has the `someString.includes(...)` and `someString.indexOf(...)`.
But in this way, I will first need to obtain the `someString`, which I think I must do by iterating the store on each keypress. Is there a smarter way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: have you tried a filter function()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is an old field change.

You can use a filter function to do that, i used this to do a intime research on a grid, but if you set the filter on combo change it will be the same.

```
var me=this,
list=me.lookup('listapdv'),
labelSearch=me.lookup('labelSearch'),
labelDelete=me.lookup('labelDelete'),
store=list.getStore();

store.clearFilter(true);
me.lookup('table').refresh();
labelSearch.setVisible(true);
labelDelete.setVisible(false);
if(newValue!==''){
    if(newValue.match(/\s/)){
        var val=newValue.toLowerCase().split(/\s/g);
        store.filter({
            filterFn:function(item){
                var ragsoc=item.get('ragsoc').toLowerCase(),
                    match=[],
                    flag=true;
                val.forEach(function(text,index){
                    if(text!==''){
                        match[index]=(ragsoc.indexOf(text)!==-1)?true:false;
                    }
                });
                match.forEach(function(f,i){
                    if(!f) flag=false;
                });
                return flag;
            }
        });
    }else{
        store.filter([{
            property:'ragsoc',
            value: newValue,
            operator:'like'
        }]);
    }
    labelSearch.setVisible(false);
    labelDelete.setVisible(true);
}
me.lookup('aziendeCount').setText(''+store.data.length);
list.setSelection(store.getAt(0));
```

Comment: What are you checking with the newValue.match(/\s/) and .split(/\s/g)? I am gonna try and use the approach with the filterFn function

Comment: sorry, if the value is something like "name surname" I split it

Comment: and create a function to match all the words divided from a space

Comment: Thanks again. But what does this expression do: newValue.match(/\s/). From what I have found out, reading about regular expressions, it means match any whitespace? But I'm not sure. Is there more into it?

Comment: Nope, \s match a whitespace, simply if there is a whitespace i do the split with the filter function, else i do a simple filter on the property, vote as correct if ok

Comment: No not yet, working on it. I will mark you post as a solution once I solve it. It has lead me on the right path. I'm debuging your code to see what exactly happens. In my case, it works the first time the user provides a key. So if I press 'x', it will show the names that only has x in it. But the second time it won't work. So for it to work again, one has to refresh the page. But working on it :-)

Comment: If you need help add a sencha fiddle to your question